# Is it possible to call library functions from template file?

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to call a library function from within the chef template?
I know we can pass it as variables but my requirement is to iterate over a list in the template file can call the function for each list element.

/libraries/default.rb

```
 module Common
  module Helper
      def test_fun(receiver)
          if receiver['bla_bla']
             return <something meaningful>
      end
```

/templates/default.rb

```
<% Chef::Resource::User.send(:include, Common::Helper) -%>
<% node['receivers'].each do |receiver| -%>
<% test_fun([receiver]) -%>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first line in the template (the `include` bit) and add `extend self` to the top of the Helper module and call it as `Common::Helper.test_fun(whatever)`.